# Create playlist in code

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How can you create a media player playlist in code in Windows Phone 8? I have done some research but I couldn't find a way, yet. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in feature for manipulating Playlist in Windows Phone 8. However,
You can create a list of songs you want to play:

```
    Collection<string> songs = new Collection<string>();
    songs.Add("http://freedownloads.last.fm/download/86983340/Petrolero.mp3");
```

Then you have to control your "playlist" manually:

```
    foreach(var song in songs)
        MediaPlayer.Play(Song.FromUri("Song name", new Uri(song)));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to create playlists on Windows Phone.
You can vote for it on [user voice](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3846846-sync-edit-playlists-with-windows-phone-8).